# Laravel send email connection could not be established [connection timeout #110]

Tags: php, email, laravel-5, swiftmailer

I have a send email feature on my project. I'm using Laravel's mailer (SwiftMailer) to do this. The error is that, on some network, the email was successfully sent, but on other network, it will display the error:

> Connection could not be established with host smtp.gmail.com [connection time out #110]

Can anybody help to find the issues ?

Comment: This is most likely an issue related to servers. Something, on "other network" is blocking the connection to the mail server (could be your ISP, could be a VPN that you're using, could be the shared hosting you're using)... Anyway, doesn't seem like a code related issue.

Comment: @milz so, if I deploy the app to production server, there won't be any issues if my setting on the server is correct?

Comment: That's my assumption. If you have the proper code and the email is (always) sent on the development environment it's safe to assume that it will work on the production server as long as server, domain and email server are correctly configured.